# Time and Date Column combine

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have my Date Column as:
I have Date and Time column in csv which is as follows:

```
2020/01/02  12:20
2020/01/02  12:22
2020/01/02  12:36
2020/01/02  12:37
2020/01/02  12:38
2020/01/02  12:39
2020/01/02  13:20
2020/01/02  13:21
2020/01/02  13:42
2020/01/02  13:47
2020/01/02  13:50
2020/01/02  13:51
2020/01/02  13:54
2020/01/02  13:56
```

I want to combine this two column and make it a single column with values like:

```
2020-01-02 12:20:00
2020-01-02 12:22:00
```

and so on.

How do I do this?

Comment: please provide the sample data instead of image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can convert the `DATE` column to datetime and `TIME` column to timedelta. `pd.to_timedelta()` expects `hh:mm:ss` format so `(df['TIME'] + ':00')` provides `00` seconds for all `TIME`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['2020-05-12 00:00:00', '09:19']], columns=['DATE', 'TIME'])

df['NEW_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']) + pd.to_timedelta((df['TIME'] + ':00'))

df
#   DATE        TIME                  NEW_DATE
# 0 2020-05-12 00:00:00 09:19   2020-05-12 09:19:00
```

NOTE: Incase you get error with `(df['TIME'] + ':00')` try `(df['TIME'].astype(str) + ':00')`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. I was missing how to covert the time into ':00'. That was the key to my problem.

Comment: I don't think you need timedelta here; concatenate the date and time string, then parsing with to_datetime should do fine.

Comment: @MrFuppes actually the first question had '2020-05-12 00:00:00' that is why I chose to do so, you can check in the edits.

Comment: You mean the date column was already datetime datatype? Then using timedelta / adding time as such is the right thing to do!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.combine(datetime.strptime("5 Mar 12", "%d %b %y"),datetime.strptime("0130","%H%M").time())
```